# Google place api is not supporting multiple types

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

when i provide the url given below , i am getting the proper rsults but

```
    String baseUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=";
    String last="&radius=20000&types=school&sensor=false&key=";

    URL = baseUrl + latitude + "," + longitude + last + API_KEY ;
```

when i am trying to use multiple types like :

> school | university

it showing forced closed....EX

```
 String baseUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=";
    String last="&radius=20000&types=school|university&sensor=false&key=";

    URL = baseUrl + latitude + "," + longitude + last + API_KEY ;
```

what mistake i am doing...

Comment: Please post the log so we can see the exception you are getting and a stack trace.

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.run.trial/com.run.trial.RuntrialActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)

Comment: The above url request works fine for me, maybe your application is breaking when no result is returned? Do you have a check for status?

Comment: did you use comma instead of pipe?

Answer (score 4):

This works for me when using multiple types:

```
String keyString = "your_key";

String JSON_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=";
String types = "airport|hospital";
try {
        placesSearchStr=JSON_BASE+getLat()+","+getLng()+
                        "&radius=1000&sensor=false&types="+URLEncoder.encode(types,"UTF-8")+
                        "&key="+keyString;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The emphasis here is on `types="+URLEncoder.encode(types,"UTF-8")`

Answer (score 0):

Hi friend i had same problem like you,after long time searching i found another solution for parsing google response using Volley api 
 http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-%E2%80%93-volley-library
 [Volley library for Android parse xml response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962904/volley-library-for-android-parse-xml-response)

volley liabrery has no request for xml but have string request and response, you can convert string into xml format than parse data as xml

Answer (score 0):

I friend now i got the multiple types support now. use uri builder class request url

```
public String getURL(double lat, double lng){
    Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
    .scheme("https")
    .authority("maps.googleapis.com")
    .path("maps/api/place/search/xml")
    .appendQueryParameter("location", lat+",",lng)
    .appendQueryParameter("radius", "5000")
    .appendQueryParameter("types",   "zoo|travel_agency|taxi_stand|pet_store|museum|movie_theater|library|jewelry_store|hospital|clothing_store|atm|church|bus_station|art_gallery|bank|beauty_salon|city_hall|book_store|park|shopping_mall|train_station|airport")
    .appendQueryParameter("sensor", "true")
    .appendQueryParameter("key", "your key")
    .build();
    return uri.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put parameters like where types like `String types = "cafe|restaurant";`:

```
try {
    HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
    HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
            .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_SEARCH_URL));
    request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
    request.getUrl().put("location", _latitude + "," + _longitude);
    request.getUrl().put("radius", _radius); // in meters
    request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");

    if(types != null)
        request.getUrl().put("types", types);

    PlacesList list = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);
    // Check log cat for places response status
    Log.d("Places Status", "" + list.status);
    return list;

} catch (HttpResponseException e) {
    Log.e("Error:", e.getMessage());
    return null;
}
```