# Android Volley Server XML Request

Tags: java, android, xml

I am working on an Android App and using Volley library. The response for some of the requests are in XML format. I searched for Android Volley tutorial on how to deal with XML, but can't seem to find.

The only option at this point for me is:

1. Use StringRequest to get the Server Response as String
2. Parse String and traverse it?

Here's the source of Volley:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/43950676303ff68b23a8b469d6a534ccd1e08cfc/src/com/android/volley/toolbox

I don't see any class dealing with XML Objects.

Any other advice. Help???

Comment: This seems to be related, good luck. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962904/volley-library-for-android-parse-xml-response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone posted in comment, it has been answered here:

[Volley library for Android parse xml response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962904/volley-library-for-android-parse-xml-response)

Volley do not directly provide an XML Object. Your approach of taking the response as String and then inflating to XMLObject is the way I did it.

I made a Class for parsing XML Responses from Server (Combining GsonRequest with Simple). Here's the Class Code Snippet: [SimpleXmlRequest](http://gist.github.com/itsalif/6149365)

At first it takes the response from Server as String. Then, it uses Simple Serialization tool (http://simple.sourceforge.net/) to inflate the response to XML Object.

Answer (score 0):

[gson-xml](https://github.com/stanfy/gson-xml) integrated with [GsonRequest](https://gist.github.com/ficusk/5474673) may be your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is something i wrote few weeks back to use with volley. It uses [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) Serialization for xml parsing and is very much similar to GSON.

**CODE :**

```
public class XmlGsonRequest<T> extends Request<T> {

public static final int XML_REQUEST = 1;
public static final int GSON_REQUEST = 2;

private Gson mGson;
private Serializer mSerializer;
private final Class<T> mClazz;
private final Listener<T> mListener;
private final int mRequestType;


public XmlGsonRequest(int method, int requestType, String url, Class<T> clazz, Listener<T> listener,
        ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, errorListener);
    mClazz = clazz;
    mListener = listener;
    mRequestType = requestType;
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
    mListener.onResponse(response);
}

@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String source = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));

        if (mRequestType == XML_REQUEST) {

            mSerializer = new Persister();
            Reader reader = new StringReader(source);
            return Response.success(mSerializer.read(mClazz, reader, false),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));

        } else if (mRequestType == GSON_REQUEST) {

            mGson = new Gson();
            return Response.success(mGson.fromJson(source, mClazz), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));

        } else {
            return null;
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}
}
```