# How to set charset in xml data in volley android

Tags: android, android-volley

I got problem with data server get a xml data with this: "?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?" and string can't show me special chars ( paÅº ), how can i fix it?
I tried to change the encoding on UTF-8 and UTF-16 but didn't work or my way was bad. Any idea?

```
public boolean loadDataFromRest( Context context){
    String szUrl = "http://host";
    alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder( context );

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest( Request.Method.GET, szUrl,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String szResponse) {
                            Log.d("DEBUG ", szResponse);
                }
```

Comment: You need to implement the `getHeaders()` method too.

Comment: See this example for `getHeaders()` : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19601084/2235972

Comment: I tested: headers.put("Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=utf-8"); (8 and 16) but still didn't work :/

Comment: IMO, you can read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962904/volley-library-for-android-parse-xml-response if you have not read it before

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code to debug your response. I am getting all the body contents in response.data but not in StringResponse that uses parseCharset()

```
                @Override
                protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                    String StringResponse = "";
                    try {
                        StringResponse = new String(response.data,
                                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                        HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers);
                        Log.d(TAG, "--> Response Headers " + response.headers);
                        Log.d(TAG, "--> String Status Code " + response.statusCode);
                        Log.d(TAG, "--> String response data :  " + new String(response.data));
                        System.out.println("--> string response is " + StringResponse);
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
                    }
                    return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
                }
```