# JSON Parsing runtime error source not found in android

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps

I'm trying to do json parse for getting city state and zipcode.
I'm using google api for this.

I debug the below code on two devices android 2.3 and android 4.1.2.
in android 2.3 its works fine.but in android 4.1.2 i got runtime error.

here is a my code

```
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+address+"&sensor=true";
JSONParser jparser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jobject = jparser.getJSONFromUrl(url);



try {
      DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost httpPost= new HttpPost(url);
      HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
      HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
      is = httpEntity.getContent();
}catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

on the `HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);` line i got an runtime error Source not fount from ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity.
please sort it out my problem

Answer (score 1):

please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18259495/1944782 , append url parameter and make url according your requirement. After doing this, please put your code in the AsyncTask Background and call AsyncTask from your main Activity. Hope your problem would be solved after doing this.

**Update**

please refer this code:

```
public JSONObject getAddressData() {

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+address+"&sensor=true");
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response;
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

try {
    response = client.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
    int b;
    while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
        stringBuilder.append((char) b);
    }
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
}

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
try {
    jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return jsonObject;
```

}

Comment: i did what u said but still i got the same error on the same place.

Answer (score 0):

> I hope this is Help you,You get Exact Address location using this code

```
public String gpsadd() {
    try {


    if(isGPS) {


                Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(Home.this, Locale.getDefault());
         try 
          {
            addflg=0;
            lat=location.getLatitude();
            lng=location.getLongitude();
            boolean lop=true;
            while(lop) {
            List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) 
            {
                lop=false;
                addflg=1;
                address = addresses.get(0);
                s_addr=address.getAddressLine(0)+" "+address.getAddressLine(1)+" "+address.getAddressLine(2);
                disp="Location\n "+address.getAddressLine(0)+"\n"+address.getAddressLine(1)+"\n"+address.getAddressLine(2);

            }

            }


          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
    } else {
        display("GPS not Enabled");

    }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return disp;
}
```